# ImageView's scale type unexpected behavior

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, imageview, android-5.0-lollipop

I have an ImageView with `scaleType="fitCenter"` and `layout_width="match_parent"`, so I expect the image inside it to scale and inflate all view.

Layout file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/border" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="6dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/myImageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/aaa"
            android:transitionName="image" />

        <!-- Some other views... -->
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

The problem begins when images are too small (for example, 50x50 px) and it doesn't work as expected on all devices.

The image below shows the difference between API 16 and 22.

[image: screenshot]

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: Did you try setting `adjustViewBounds="true"`? Maybe this will unify the behaviour across different Android apis.

Comment: @blipinsk Yes, I tried and it did not help.

Comment: Can you post you entire layout file? Maybe the problem lays somewhere else.

Comment: I think you have different layouts (or style) for different api. Do you have separate resource folders for v-11, 14, and 21 ?

Comment: @inmyth no, that's not the case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not with your code but with the way `android:adjustViewBounds` work. This is documented in `setAdjustViewBounds` method of [ImageView](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/ImageView.java).

> Note:If the application targets API level 17 or lower,
>   adjustViewBounds will allow the drawable to shrink the view bounds,
>   but not grow to fill available measured space in all cases.

Based on the post [Correct the ImageView's adjustViewBounds behaviour on API Level 17 and below with AdjustableImageView](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/correct-imageview-adjustviewbounds-with-adjustable-imageview/en) by nuuneoi, the possible solution for this issue is to use custom [`AdjustableImageView`](https://github.com/nuuneoi/AdjustableImageView).

**Code:**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewParent;
import android.widget.ImageView;

/**
 * Created by nuuneoi on 2/17/15 AD.
 */
public class AdjustableImageView extends ImageView {

    boolean mAdjustViewBounds;

    public AdjustableImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public AdjustableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public AdjustableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public void setAdjustViewBounds(boolean adjustViewBounds) {
        mAdjustViewBounds = adjustViewBounds;
        super.setAdjustViewBounds(adjustViewBounds);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        Drawable mDrawable = getDrawable();
        if (mDrawable == null) {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
            return;
        }

        if (mAdjustViewBounds) {
            int mDrawableWidth = mDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
            int mDrawableHeight = mDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
            int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
            int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
            int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);

            if (heightMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY && widthMode != MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
                // Fixed Height & Adjustable Width
                int height = heightSize;
                int width = height * mDrawableWidth / mDrawableHeight;
                if (isInScrollingContainer())
                    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
                else
                    setMeasuredDimension(Math.min(width, widthSize), Math.min(height, heightSize));
            } else if (widthMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY && heightMode != MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
                // Fixed Width & Adjustable Height
                int width = widthSize;
                int height = width * mDrawableHeight / mDrawableWidth;
                if (isInScrollingContainer())
                    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
                else
                    setMeasuredDimension(Math.min(width, widthSize), Math.min(height, heightSize));
            } else {
                super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
            }
        } else {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }

    private boolean isInScrollingContainer() {
        ViewParent p = getParent();
        while (p != null && p instanceof ViewGroup) {
            if (((ViewGroup) p).shouldDelayChildPressedState()) {
                return true;
            }
            p = p.getParent();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:scaleType="fitXY"` to Scale the image using FILL that you are looking for.

Comment: It fills the view but also distorts the image.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `fitXy` the image fills the view in both dimensions, disregarding its aspect ratio. This will undoubtedly cause distortion.

Another option is `centerCrop`. This scale type will rescale the image until both dimensions x or y are greater or equal to the container while preserving aspect ratio. The result will be centered inside the view.

`fitCenter` would be the opposite of centerCrop. It scales the image until at least one dimension x or y is smaller or equal to the view.

That said, the behavior that you show in the screenshots has more to do with screen sizes, not api level.